# C/C++, сбор информации о состоянии системы на базе GNU/Linux дистрибутива

Tags: c++, linux, c, мониторинг

Необходимо получить всю информацию о состоянии системы на базе дистрибутива GNU/Linux средствами C/C++, Libc и других системных библиотек в составе дистрибутивов: отследить состояние процессора, каждого ядра процессора, каждого процесса, количество пользователей, количество текущих пользователей, памяти, сервисов.

В /proc/pid/, например, есть очень много информации, но открывать на каждый процесс файл (и не один десяток) - дело такое себе конечно.

В /var/run/utmp есть информация о всех текущих пользователях в системе, опять же, открытие файла.

Я в курсе, что всё можно получить из конкретного файла, но не думаю, что это единственный способ и что он верный (этож сколько надо файлов открыть/закрыть на дерево процессов).

2 вопроса:

1. Можно ли всё получить (например, из /proc/*) не открывая файлы?
2. Есть ли какой-то принцип и правило, по которому понятно, какую именно информацию (из каких директорий или псевдо-файловых систем) возможно получить только через открытие файла?

Comment: Поскольку принцип юникса это «всё есть файл», это именно что верный и зачастую единственный способ

Comment: Хотя тормознутость /proc уже давно заметили, но каких-то значимых улучшений в этом плане до сих пор особо не было https://habr.com/ru/articles/275545/

Comment: В линукс и системные часы и  порт USB, и процессы в памяти, и сокеты - это все файлы.  Есть библиотечки, оборачивающие существующие низкоуровневые интерфейсы во что-то удобоваримое - libproc например.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie, libproc тоже с файлами работает? Или что вы назвали низкоуровневыми интерфейсами. Просто сперва "все файлы", а потом "низкоуровневые интерфейсы" :)

Comment: @nx4n  там не все что есть , доступно через /proc . Или в текстовом виде. /proc  - это уже вторичное представление

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie, спасибо за информацию )

Answer (score 0):

Используй /proc/cpuinfo для получения информации о процессоре, sysinfo для получения информации о памяти, и /proc для получения информации о запущенных процессах.